# Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-3\rangle$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle x-3\rangle$ a field?
My thought: This quotient ring means that all polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ are evaluated at $x=3$. So this is basically isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and thus it will be field.
         Did I make right justification? Please help anybody.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint/Solution:**  $ \frac {\bf Z[x]}{<x-3>} \cong \bf Z$ (using the map $f :\bf Z[x]  \to \bf Z$, $f(x) \to f(3)$)

Comment: Z[x]/<x-3>=Z3[x] is it not correct?

Comment: No its not,see the answer by quid!

Comment: @user1991 No, though it is true that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/<3>$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$

Answer (score 3):

No it is not a field. Your reasoning is wrong in that the structure given by  "evaluating at $3$" does not give something isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3$ (neither does it give $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ which however would not be a field anyway).

Just try it evaluating $X$ you get $3$, evaluating $X+1$ you get $4$, evaluating $X-5$ you get $-2$ and so on. You can get any integer you want. The quotient is isomorphic to the integers. This is not a field.

More generally, and likely not relevant for you the quotient of this ring by a principal ideal can never be a field, as the ring has dimension $2$, and a principal ideal thus is never a maximal ideal.

Comment: I have one confusion . Is not $\langle x-3 \rangle $  a maximal ideal  of  $\mathbb Z[x]$ $?$  Commutative ring with identity  quotiented  by a maximal  ideal  should be a field . What am I getting wrong $?$

Comment: See his last sentence.

Comment: @T.S.L : I have not learnt the *dimension of ring*  things at all .   Is there any other way of explaining $?$

Comment: Can you find a proper ideal containing $(x-3)$?

Comment: @user118494 no it is not a maximal ideal. For example, it'd be contained in $\langle x-3, 2 \rangle$ Or, while circular in this context, it is not maximal *because* the qutient is not a field. In $Q[X]$ though your ideal would be maximal.

Answer (score 0):

All polynomials are indeed evaluated at $3$. Observe that as a result of this, all polynomials of the form $n$ where $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ are preserved. In particular the polynomial $3$ is not mapped to zero, as you claim, but to $3$. The resulting ring is indeed $\mathbb{Z}$.